# Showing a List in a View then passing it to a HttpPost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Hi this is very simple but is not working for me.

This is my **View**:

```
@model iLeadsTest.ViewModels.SaveViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Clients", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Pin Number</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FileClasses.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FileClasses[i].PinNumberProperty)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FileClasses[i].FirstNameProperty)
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FileClasses[i].LastNameProperty)
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.FileName);
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

My **ViewModel**:

```
public class SaveViewModel 
{
     public string FileName { get; set; }
     public List<Clients> FileClasses { get; set; }
}
```

**Why when I go to the method in my controller I'm getting an empty list?**

Comment: Because you do not create any form controls for properties of `Clients` (and nor should you - just get the data again from the repository if you need it in the POST method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that data is comming from a File, I need to show it and then pass it in the view and then pass it to my Post to save it.

Comment: Does not matter where the data is coming from. Your view has code to only display items inside the loop. It will not post those to your httppost action as you are not generating any input fields for those items.

Comment: What do you mean coming from a File? Your data is coming from the controller which knows the data. It would be pointless extra overhead to generate form controls to send it all to the client and then send it all back again unchanged.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean before showing it on the View. Ok so if I just want to show the info in my view then send it back to the controller in case the User accepts, what should I use?

Comment: Just get the information again (just as you did in the GET method). Otherwise you would need to generate a hidden input for each property of each item (e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FileClasses[i].PinNumberProperty)`)

Comment: Because you are just displaying your FileClasses sa <td>. If you want to post it, then you should use <input>.